# Minimal example for autowire and upickle

Tags: scala.js, upickle

I am not quite getting how the [minimal example](https://github.com/lihaoyi/autowire) can be applied to my web app.

In the client code I override the `doCall` method:

```
override def doCall(req: Request) = {
   println(req)
   MyServer.routes.apply(req)
}
```

But how can the client know about `MyServer`?

Of course, here it works since all code is in the same file, but in reality the client and server communicate via the *shared* crossproject.

Do I need to write the `doCall` explicitly with `dom.ext.Ajax.post`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is the [longer example](https://github.com/lihaoyi/workbench-example-app/tree/autowire). The *minimal* example demonstrates the Autowire API *within the same project* (not extremely useful). The longer example demonstrates a true client/server interaction.

For example, [it shows](https://github.com/lihaoyi/workbench-example-app/blob/autowire/example/js/src/main/scala/example/ScalaJSExample.scala#L13-L24) how `doCall` can be implemented with an AJAX call:

```scala
object Client extends autowire.Client[Js.Value, Reader, Writer]{
  override def doCall(req: Request): Future[Js.Value] = {
    dom.ext.Ajax.post(
      url = "/api/" + req.path.mkString("/"),
      data = upickle.json.write(Js.Obj(req.args.toSeq:_*))
    ).map(_.responseText)
     .map(upickle.json.read)
  }

  def read[Result: Reader](p: Js.Value) = readJs[Result](p)
  def write[Result: Writer](r: Result) = writeJs(r)
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I just wanted to be sure I am not missing something obvious. Honestly, the minimal example is really irritating since the code is not even compatible with the current upickle version.